# How can I get the RDS host of an elastic beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

How can I get the RDS host of an elastic beanstalk environment? I setup an EB env with:

`eb create --database ...`

Now I want to upload a SQL dump to this new environment without connecting to any server of this EB environment. Since the information is in the environment variables, I thought I could find out it with `eb printenv` but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

the information exists in the beanstalk web console (Data Tier section on the environment's Configuration page) as [described in this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html)

Comment: thanks for you replay, but I search a solution over terminal or via SDK